# Why can't results of arithmetic expressions including int and long variables be assigned back to int variable?

Tags: java, casting, integer, int, long-integer

I know that numeric literals in Java are by default of the type int.
So the 5 in the following example actually is an int as long as I don't write an 'L' behind it. So why can't I assign the result of a*b back to an int variable, if 5 and 7 are both of the type int?

```
long a = 5;
int b = 7;
int c = a * b;
```

I do not understand why Java has problems seeing something like this as long:

```
long a = 345236577970;
```

but still performs a typecast if the expression includes a long variable, even though its type is actually int. Super basic beginner question, sorry.

Comment: "even though its type is actually int" - the type *isn't* `int`. The type of the expression `a * b` is `long`. Just because *you* can see the value here doesn't mean that the Java compiler treats this as a constant expression in the range of `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is that 5 and 7 (both int) are assigned to variables which are then multiplied so the result should be an int. The flaw in this reasoning is that your code is not multiplying 5 and 7, but `a` and `b`. Once constants are assigned to these variables it's irrelevant what the type of the constant is: the only thing that matters is the type of the variable. In this case the types are `long` and `int` so the result is a `long`.

Simple options to convert to int is to cast or to use `Math.toIntExact`

Comment: Makes sense.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before the computation is done, there's no way to know what the result will be (which seems obvious but sometimes needs to be said out loud).  It could be a result that could fit in an `int`, but it might not be -- it could be a `long`.  So the language is designed to require that the result be of a type that could fit the largest possible range of results.

If you want to stuff the final result back into an `int`, you can certainly cast it into an `int` variable, but you do open yourself up to the risk that the result might not fit in there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think what confuses me about it is that  numeric literals by default are of the type `int`, but as soon as I use my `long` variable a (example above) in an expression it is treated as `long` even though i did not wite an "L" behind it. It makes sense due to the declaration of a as a `long` variable, but why then treat its value as an `int` by default in the first place?